# How to write a program to call a differential equation 50 times using FOR loop in MATLAB using ode23s?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, ode

I need two solve two differential equations depending upon the different values of `vin` 50 times.
My code is written as:

```
for i=1:1
[T,Y]=ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[t0 .00025],X(:,1)) 
vin =-12;
[T1,Y1]=ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[.00025 .0005],Y(end,:))
vin=12
[T2,Y2]=ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[.0005 .00075],Y1(end,:))
vin=-12
[T3,Y3]=ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[.00075 .001],Y2(end,:))
end
Tf=[T;T1;T2;T3];
Xf=[Y;Y1;Y2;Y3];
```

Now I need to do this for 100 cycles that is upto Y50 and T50 using `for` loop
How do I do that?

Comment: Use a cell array to store the output : `T{1}`, `T{2}`... instead of using `T1`, `T2`. At the end you can concatenate all the output using `Tf = [T{:}]`. Do the same with `Y`.

Comment: That's with storage.But what about calling `[T2,Y2]=ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[.0005 .00075],Y1(end,:))` 50 times

Comment: Error encountered:`Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in ttt (line 13)
[T{i},Y{i}]=ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[0 .0001*k],X(:,1))`

Comment: You could also think about using https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odextend.html, I'm not sure if it keeps the "Refine" values in the data of the solution structure.

Comment: No, you are getting it wrong I guess. In the time span of `0-.001` only, I want to find the solution of the ode 50 times and i want to store the solution during every time step in `Xf` as [Y,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4......Y50]

Comment: @LutzLehmann Should I edit the question with the whole code for a better understanding?

Comment: Forget my first comment (deleted), I did not really notice that you did in fact change the value of `vin`. The code as it is is demonstrative enough, you could also mention the variation of `vin` in the text as motive for the segmentation. The combination of `odextend` and `deval` is still a valid alternative to the other proposed solutions.

Comment: but `odextend` extend the time span also

Comment: Yes, but that is what you actually want to do. My code suggestion was too long for a comment, so I put it in an answer, please report if there are syntax errors, or if you need to make it a little more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`odextend`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odextend.html) applied to a solution structure (the last variant of the solver call in the documentation) takes the last state and the new equation and extends the solution structure using the same solver to the new end time.

So doing

```matlab
T=linspace(0,0.025,101); 
vin = 12
sol = ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[T(1) T(2)],X0); 
for k=2:100
  vin = -vin
  sol = odextend(sol,@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),T(k+1));  
end
```

should work, my octave version does unfortunately not have `odextend` to test for syntactical correctness.

The solution can be evaluated via the contained samples and the dense output

```matlab
Tsmooth = linspace(0,0.025,2001)
Ysmooth = deval(sol,Tsmooth)

hold on;
plot(Tsmooth, Ysmooth(:,1), '-b');
plot(sol.x, sol.y(:,1), '+r');
hold off;
```

Comment: Thanks, Lutz. I also figured another approach to o the same using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an additional loop

```
sct = t0:.00025:.001;
len = length(sct)-1;

vin =-12;

for i = 1:1
    % preallocate memory
    T = NaN(1,len);
    Y = NaN(size(X,1),len);
    Y(:,1) = X(:,1);
    for j = 1:len
        [tmpT,tmpY]=ode23s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),sct(j:j+1),Y) 
        T(j) = tmpT;
        Y(:,j) = tmpY;
    end

    %TODO: do something with T & Y otherwise it will get overwritten in the next iteration of i
end
```

Comment: ,I'm getting a bit confused. Can I show you my whole code so that you can make the changes accordingly?

Comment: The code that you have shown doesnt implement the ode 100 times

Comment: What do you mean with "100 times"? This calls the `ode23s` 4 times (as in your example), which is put in a `for` loop, which is called once. Which of them should be called 100 times and where should the results go/what do you want to do with them?